# what does #include<cassert> do/ can it do

Tags: c++, include

my teacher used this include in a c++ program and didn't explain it. I was curious about what it is and what it does. I was unable to find anything helpful online. just a brief mention on how it is a debugging tool. what can I use it for?
should I even be curious about it?

```
#include <cassert>
```

Comment: Like all header files, it gives you access to the functions, types, and variables declared therein.  The header `<cassert>` gives you everything from the Standard C header `<assert.h>` but wrapped in `namespace std;`

Comment: it's a directive to the compiler to "include" the specified header file. and that's about it... headers contain function skeletons and various other "metadata", enough to let the compiler figure out if you're calling the included functions correctly, but doesn't contain any actual executable code.

Comment: [assert wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h).

Comment: It contains the macro assert , which accepts a condition as an arguement. When the condition fails, a runtime error , SIGABRT is produced.

Comment: It should not be viewed as just a "debugging tool". Rather, you should consider leaving assertions turned on in so-called "release builds", disabling them only in compilation units where measuring revealed performance problems (`assert` is made so that you can explicitly disable it per compilation unit). Making a distinction between "release builds" and "debug builds" is a strange idea in the first place when you consider that the version you'll most direly need to debug *is* the one you release to your customers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like all header files, it gives you access to the functions, types, and variables declared therein.  (And macros, let's not forget macros since they happen to be applicable in this case.)

The header `<cassert>` gives you everything from the Standard C header `<assert.h>` but wrapped in `namespace std;`  (This is a pattern, C++ provides `<cXYZ>` corresponding to each C header `<XYZ.h>`: `<cstdlib>`, `<cmath>`, etc.)

[This documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cassert) suggests that the only content is the single macro, `assert(condition)`

Answer (score 2):

This include file allows the use of the assert macro call.  An assert is used to check for fatal errors in a program and halt execution when found (for example checking that a function argument is not NULL before dereferencing).  Generally asserts are not present in code compiled in non-debug mode (ie with the define NDEBUG), but present in code compiled in debug mode.

For example you may have a function such as:

```
    void PrintString(char* str)
    {
        assert(str != NULL);
        printf(str);
    }
```

When compiled in debug mode the program will immediately halt (and usually print the location of assert) if called with a NULL value for str, but in production code the assert is a NOP and the function call will continue.  You use assert to quickly reveal function calls and situations that are unexpected or your code is not built to handle during unit testing.

Comment: Some mistakes here. `assert` is not a function but a macro, and you cannot even write `std::assert`, or else the compiler will complain.

Comment: Also, `NDEBUG` does the opposite of what you say. It disables assertions; they are turned *on* by default.

Answer (score 0):

we can understand this as if in our `code`, we write `a=2` and after that uses `assert(a)` 
and  then changes `a=0` ,calls again `assert(a)` .this will generate `assertion failed`  and abort the program execution.